# Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new on using the Javascript in asp.net and i have a problem on this code.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>item 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>item 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function setSelectedIndex(s, i) {

        s.value[i - 1].selected = true;

        return;

    }
    setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("DropDownList1"), 5);
</script>
```

Can anyone help me please.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/y7ov5jna/). Here is what you need to do:

```
<select ID="DropDownList1">
  <option>item 1</option>
  <option>item 2</option>
  <option>item 3</option>
  <option>item 4</option>
  <option>item 5</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function setSelectedIndex(s, i) {
                console.log(s, i);
                s.selectedIndex = (i-1); 
        //s.value[i - 1].selected = true;

        return;

    }
    setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("DropDownList1"), 5);
</script>
```

Comment: is there a way using the control dropdownlist  asp.net instead of  selected options.

Comment: It is just the same. You just need to update your JS code with my code. It would work. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks..I have update my js with your code iam using the control of Asp.net dropdownlist not the selected options it got an error 'Unable to set property 'selectedIndex' of undefined or null reference'.

Comment: Can you paste your generated source code from "page view source" in your question. Then I would be able to debug.

Comment: If you haven't got any further issues, then please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: i can paste the whole page source.

Comment: No, in your web browser right click on the page and click "view page source". There would be able to see the convert code from ASP to HTML. Copy that whole code with the JS code and paste that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `options` property on element variable `s` instead of the values.

Also, if it still doesn't work, ensure that the element ID `DropDownList1` is also the same on the browser. There is a healthy chance that it is slightly modified when rendered. In such a case you should select the element by its CSS class name or, try to pass the client ID of dropdown (`DropDownList1.ClientID`) to your JS code somehow.

```js
function setSelectedIndex(s, i) {

  s.options[i - 1].selected = true;

  return;

}
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("DropDownList1"), 5);
```

```html
<select ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
  <option>item 1</option>
  <option>item 2</option>
  <option>item 3</option>
  <option>item 4</option>
  <option>item 5</option>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
document.getElementById("DropDownList1").selectedIndex = i -1 ;
```